# Convert 4-byte hex color to RGB

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm having an issue trying to convert a 4-byte hex format color to RGB format, the biggest problem is the two first characters of the 4-byte hex color and i dunno how to convert it. So I have this hex: `$16750899` and want converts to format RGB (0..255,0..255,0..255)

Comment: We don't know how to convert it either.  It depends on what the input format is.  Do you know what it is?  ARGB?  BGRA? RGBA? PARGB? Etc?

Comment: @J... i don't have ideia, just know this is a TColor format

Comment: The source format is a `TColor`?  And what of the destination format?  Do you want Windows RGB format?  Or some other RGB format?  Do you want the colour channels independently?

Comment: @J... i just want to get the RGB color from Hex.

Comment: It is possible that this is what you are looking for [ColorToRGB](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Graphics.ColorToRGB) but your question is rather unclear

Comment: Hex is not color, it is just formatting.

Comment: @kobik Yes, as i have in the post.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar i updated the post question, maybe now is clear?

Comment: @William Nope. Like I said hex is not color. You can have same "hex" value but if underlying format is ARGB color it contains will be drastically different from color if the format is RGBA. You didn't say from where you get your color and what format it is. Four byte hex colors come if many different varieties. Which one you have? We can only wild guess that part.

Comment: @William That particular value has 4 channels. The fourth channel is alpha.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I got it from the .dfm, so i dunno what format it is.

Comment: You realise that I gave you the answer over an hour ago. I'm really not sure what more you could want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i'll test if it works.

Answer (score 6):

Convert the hex string to a numeric value like this:

```
var
  Color: Integer;
....
Color := StrToInt(str);
```

Your value has four channels so one assumes that the fourth channel is alpha. Pick out the color channels using `GetRValue`, `GetGValue` and `GetBValue`. Get the alpha channel like this:

```
function GetAValue(rgba: Integer): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte(rgb shr 24);
end;
```

Or you can unpack them all at once like this:

```
procedure ExtractColorChannels(rgba: Integer; out r, g, b, a: Byte);
begin
  r := Byte(rgba);
  g := Byte(rgba shr 8);
  b := Byte(rgba shr 16);
  a := Byte(rgba shr 24);
end;
```

You could then write:

```
var
  r, g, b, a: Byte;
....
ExtractColorChannels(StrToInt(str), r, g, b, a);
```

For your input of `'$16750899'` this yields the following channels:

```
Alpha: $16
Blue: $75
Green: $08
Red: $99
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have at [Colors in VCL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Colors_in_the_VCL) from the embarcadero docwiki.

As reported by the documentation:

> [...]
>
> if you specify TColor as a specific 4-byte hexadecimal number
>
> [...]
>
> the **low three bytes represent RGB color intensities** for **blue**, **green**, and **red**, respectively.

Then, you can have a look at this [code example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/ColorToRGB_(Delphi)).

I hope this links can help you.